# How to get currently viewed slide in powerpoint vsto add-in when clicked between two slides in slide pane?

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint, add-in

I know this has been asked before which I haven't satsified from the answers.

I need to ask again.

I want to access index of the slide that is currently in slide pane when I click in between two slide thumbnails in slide sorter pane.

The most satisfactory anwer is to change active pane to slide then sorter again to make the upper slide selected and then access to the id of the selected slide. Whcih is not desirable for my case.

From which I noticed that, PowerPoint itself has information of currently viewed slide when clicked in bewteen two slides and it says ith of j slides at bottom-left corner without accessing the selected slide property. Thus, I think it should be possible to find the id of the slide in view. But I don't know how.

Comment: Why is the suggested example not desirable?  Have you tried it?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried with a quick implementation with no success and will try again. This is actually will be used in the company to create company specific style presentations. Thus, anybody using this should not be confused. So it is needed not to change the users intended behavior. If there is no such way ı will insist to decision makers to accept this solution eventually.

Comment: You haven't really described why the suggested solution isn't acceptable.  Usually the complaint is that the screen flashing will startle the user, whereas it actually happens so fast that the user's not aware that anything happened.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late response. Couldn't reach to the net. Actually, it would no problem but some of the user requests that not to loose where they clicked. It is hard to make someone convince to do it in a right way. It is not a problem for me to do it in a suggested way. Thanks anyway I guess I will continue with suggested way by forcing the users.

Comment: You may have to explain to them that if they want something done to the selected slide, they need to select a slide, not the space between two slides!  ;-)

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I couldn't make it work. When I activate slide pane it just jumps to last selected slide in the thumbnail pane. I think event occurs before slide is changed in the slide pane. :S

Comment: What version of PPT are you using?

Comment: I am using 2013 and I am writing that activate the code in windowSelectionChanged function. I moved it to the function in which index is required, then it worked I guess.